# no data available label is not showing in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have one view controller with the table view. when there is data it will populate in the table view. When there is no data, then no data label have to display. I used below code. But its crash on this line:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var numOfSection: NSInteger = 0

    if (self.alldata?.count)! > 0 {

        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        numOfSection = 1

    } else {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

        noDataLabel.text = "No Data Available"
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 176.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel

    }
    return numOfSection

}
```

Crash on this line: `if (self.alldata?.count)! > 0 {`
crash : `(lldb)`. no further info i am getting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `self.alldata?.count` what this prints

Comment: Did you check if any data available in self.alldata?

Comment: Change if (self.alldata?.count)! > 0 this line to  if (self.alldata?.count) ?? 0 > 0 because you are force-unwrapping a optional value.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcefully unwrapping the array, which is nil at the time of no data. Due to that it's crashing.

Check like this

```
if let alldata = self.alldata, alldata.count > 0 {
      self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
      numOfSection = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `(self.alldata?.count)! > 0` to `self.alldata?.count ?? 0 > 0`. You are force-unwrapping the result of `(self.alldata?.count)` so if `alldata` is nil you are force-unwrapping a nil;

On the side note, it is a very bad practice to have side effects in such functions as `numberOfSections`. That function should only return the number of sections and do nothing more. Put your UI manipulation somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The crash maybe because `alldata` is nil and you try to unwrap it in `(self.alldata?.count)!`. Try modifying it like

```
if self.alldata.count != nil && (self.alldata?.count)! > 0 {
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
    numOfSection = 1
}
```